# How to modify an Effect to work with multiple requests called?

Tags: rxjs, observable, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I've written this Effect to handle one call at a time:

```
@Effect()
   indexCollectiveDocuments$ = this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType<IndexCollectiveDocuments>(CollectiveIndexingActionTypes.IndexCollectiveDocuments),
      mergeMapTo(this.store.select(getIndexingRequest)),
      exhaustMap((request: any[], index: number) => {
         return zip(...request.map(item => {
            this.currentItem = item;
            return this.indexingService.indexDocuments(item).pipe(
               map((response: any[]) => new IndexCollectiveDocumentsSuccess(response)),
               catchError(error => of(new IndexCollectiveDocumentsFailure({ error: error, item: this.currentItem })))
            )
         }))
      })
   );
```

It does dispatch both Success and Failure actions according to the request result.

But when I feed the effect with multiple items(which are the payload of **getIndexingRequest**) to send requests one after another, the Success and Failure actions are not dispatched accordingly, cancels when one is failed.

How do I modify it so that it works with multiple requests, rather than one?

EDIT: I can see all the requests and their results in the network tab. But only one action is dispatched.

Comment: You want to make multiple `IndexCollectiveDocumentsSuccess` actions?

Comment: Say I make two HTTP requests. The first is failed, I want a Fail action dispatched. If the second one succeeds, I want Success action dispatched. But if one of them is failed, the stream stops and no action is called. @martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the RxJS operator `exhaustMap` which will cancel incoming requests when there is already one request running.

To run all requests use either `mergeMap` (run parallel) or `concatMap` (run serial).